# Scala case class : copy non equal/ hascode members

Tags: scala, copy, case-class

I want to use copy on a case classes. But scala insists I specify all the properties that were declared in the second paranthsis.

Example:

```
package academic.classes.casec.copy

object TstClz {
  val f = DataMe("SD") ( "B")
  val x = f.copy("x 4")()//Error : not enough arguments for method copy: (b: String, c: String)academic.classes.casec.copy.DataMe. Unspecified value parameters b, c.
}

case class DataMe (a : String, a1 : String = "a1")(b:String, c: String = ""){}
```

Is this a feature or a bug? What can I do to make it work the way I want (get the values of b and c from the instance whose copy is being made?

Comment: Any reason to use a curried case class constructor?

Comment: I think `copy` doesn't "inherit" default arguments of the constructor (from the subsequent argument lists), so you either have to give it all arguments, or make them in one argument list in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
object TstClz {
  val f = DataMe("SD") ( "B")
  val x = f.copy("x 4")(b = f.b, c = f.c)
}

case class DataMe (a : String, a1 : String = "a1")(val b:String, val c: String = "") {}
```

Adding only `b = f.b, c = f.c` is not enough, it seems parameters from the seconds list do not define `case class` values by default, and without marking them with `val` even simple f.b access will fail. Moreover, `copy` seems to be defined as returning a function with two arguments, but with no default values for them.

Note: I have tested this both with 2.11.8 and 2.12.0. I think [the commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/6c7f2b6460de1aa6d15a6005921ca50e98a54027) fxlae referenced in his answer did not revert the behaviour completely, as in the commit there is this source comment:

> Copy only has defaults on the first parameter list, as of SI-5009.

(The commit is marked as present in 2.12.0).

As you wrote in your comment, you can add your own copy implementation if preferred, so that all `val`s have their defaults:

```
def copy(a: String = a, a1: String = a1, b: String = b, c: String = c): DataMe = {
  DataMe(a, a1)(b, c)
}
```

Comment: This is some workaround at least. Maybe will make my own fn that takes the instance and copies it self like this

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that's possible. In [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5009) bug report, you can find the following statement:

> Martin says: case class ness is only bestowed on the first argument list
>
> the rest should not be copied.

Later, there was a ["bug fix"](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/40e7cab7a22a8531bdd310bfb57fda51b798c690) which made `copy` to return at least a function representing the second parameter list, but that behavior was reverted in this [commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/6c7f2b6460de1aa6d15a6005921ca50e98a54027).

Comment: Thank you for finding that. I was expecting that it was a feature. Wish there was a a way to flag that we want the other behaviour as another feature.